# Flutter dependency in java plugin

Tags: android, flutter

I have opened android plugin of Firebase Auth but I cannot access flutter dependencies. What can I do to be able to use features like autocomplete?

When I run the code, everything works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alright, there is an easy solution for that!
Open Android studio and open the map viewer and make sure you are in the `Project` view. 
[image: Picture showing project view]

Now create a new directory and call it something like tmplibs.
[image]

Alright, now navigate to your Flutter SDK directory. So where you cloned the Flutter repo. Then open the `bin` folder, after that the `cache` folder, followed by the `artifacts` folder, now open the `engine` folder and finally open the `android-x64` folder.
So the path will look something like this:

```
...\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-x64
```

In here, you'll find a file called `flutter.jar`. Copy that and paste it in your new `tmplibs` folder! 
[image]

Now right click on the `flutter.jar` file in project view in Android studio and click on `Add As Library...`
[image]

Now open your module settings
[image]

Finally click on `Dependencies` and changes the scope of `tmplibs/flutter.jar` to provided.
[image]

That's it!

Comment: Why is this required? I've got coworkers on Macs that this isn't necessary for but for me on windows I had to add this reference

Answer (score 1):

A better solution is to use the android project of the example app instead of the library. See this issue response on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11632

Comment: Could you please explain how? How would the change on example will be applied on the actual plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

[Bram Vanbilsen's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46372892/14743281) resolves the problem. But comment the implementation line in build.gradle file after building the plugin.

```
dependencies {
  implementation files('tmplibs/flutter.jar')
}
```

If you run the example app without commenting the above line, it produces Duplicate dependencies error as the flutter source is included in the example app's build.gradle file.